# static ImmutableArray is not initialized

Tags: c#, .net, immutablearray

I have one internal static class MyLists with a static member:

```cs
internal static ImmutableArray<string> MyList = 
    new ImmutableArray<string> { "asd", "qwe" };
```

In another public test class Tests I have a MyTest function which selects and compares the list.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class MyTests {
  [TestMethod]
  public void TestMyLists() {
    var list = MyLists.MyList.Select(s => s + ".foo");
  }
}
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Additional information: The type initializer for 'TestMyLists' threw an exception.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When I debug I see the static ImmutableArray as value = Uninitialized. Why?

Comment: What value od Lists or Lists.List?

Comment: what is Lists here? not a good practice to name your local variables same as pre-defined ones. for eg: List

Comment: I think you're supposed to use a factory method to create an ImmutableArray

Comment: Is there static constructor in that TestLists class? If yes, need to check it's code. If not - need to check all static fields definitions (like that "List"). Some of these throws NullReferenceException.

Comment: this is a mockup, not actual names from code

Comment: Well then need to check all that for the real class which mocked up name is "TestMyLists" in question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the docs on [ImmutableArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablearray.create), you should use the `Create()` method instead of using constructor for this type of array, like this:

```cs
internal static ImmutableArray<string> List = ImmutableArray.Create("asd", "qwe");
```

About the reason why, I will point you to the article [Please welcome ImmutableArray](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/please-welcome-immutablearrayt/) by Immo Landwerth, where he describes:

> The default value of `ImmutableArray<T>` has the underlying array initialized with a null reference. In this case it behaves the same way as an `ImmutableArray<T>` that has been initialized with an empty array, i.e. the `Length` property returns 0 and iterating over it simply doesn’t yield any values. In most cases this is the behavior you would expect. However, in some cases you may want to know that the underlying array hasn’t been initialized yet. For that reason `ImmutableArray<T>` provides the property `IsDefault` which returns true if the underlying array is a `null` reference. For example you can use that information to implement lazy initialization.

Comment: My VS2015 is not seeing the Create method. Any ideas why? I have 
    using System.Collections.Immutable;
Edit: Youre not supposed to specify <string>

Comment: Create() method should be within the same package as the ImmutableArray - received from NuGet package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable/

Check if You have the latest version & all dependencies required.